# Is there a way to calculate the confidence in global optimum from a Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, confidence-interval

Is there a mathematical way of providing a confidence value based on the parameters of a Genetic Algorithm?

A simplistic way would be looking at how much of the search space has been explored, but I feel this would be underestimating the value as a GA is meant to narrow the search and approximate global optimum without considering the entire search space.

The reason I need it is because I wrote a GA around the [Kemeny-Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemeny%E2%80%93Young_method) algorithm, and it would be useful to provide some sort of number estimating my confidence on the output.

Comment: I would think that confidence in the optimum isn't possible without some additional information regarding the objective function. GAs are heuristic and at least sometimes heuristics perform amazingly poorly. The optimum could be a very tall narrow spike in an otherwise smooth fitness landscape with just a few small hills. If your initial population misses the immediate neighborhood of the spike then the GA probably converges to one of the small hills.

Comment: That's my problem as well. However, could I make some sort of judgement based on my mutation and crossover rates? Even an extremely probabilistic one is fine.